How can I reference sky photos to a star map?
On Earth, it is straightforward to georeference images onto a map surface using control points. Is there a similar approach for photos of the night sky showing stars?
I’ll take a long exposure shot of the night sky and want to use the stars as control points to overlay the image on Stellarium to identify all the objects in the picture. Is that feasible (I know the relevant camera parameters and my geolocation)?

See https://nova.astrometry.net/

Yes.
The method is called plate-solving or astrometric solving. There are websites which offer that service as well as tools which work locally on your computer:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_astrometric_solvers
Quite a few of the astrophotographers in my local observatory use the online version of astrometry.net

Thank you @planetmaker. This was a very interesting read, I've never heard of this before. I will have a look at some of the software mentioned in the list!
